Merge local version of code into develop branch without losing changes
Our company is working on a certain version of an application with two divisions. The main division that originally made the application uses Perforce as version control and we use Git.
We need to develop some separate features and got a zipped version of their code. We created a new Repo and added their code to safely work together on it in our division with multiple people. The other division will send updated versions again through a .zip file.
I already tried making a new branch, replace our local files with theirs and push those changes. But that seems to overwrite all of our existing features we added.
How can we merge their new code into ours, without deleting all the changes/features we made?

Which platform/Service is your git repository hosted? Azure DevOps, GitHub or other platforms?

"I already tried making a new branch, replace our local files with theirs and push those changes. But that seems to overwrite all of our existing features we added." If you do that on your main branch then commit, yes it will overwrite your changes. Do it on a new branch, then merge it into your main, so that it generates conflicts.

You can do like as below in your Git repository:

Create a new branch (e.g., feature) based on the default branch (main or master).

Create a new branch (e.g., Perforce) based on the feature branch to receive the modified files from Perforce.

At the same time, also create a new branch (e.g., develop) to based on the feature branch to let you commit your changes.

After you commit changes to develop branch, merge the changes from develop branch to feature branch.

Copy and commit the modified files from Perforce into the Perforce branch to overwrite the files with the same filenames.

Try to merge the changes from Perforce branch to feature branch. If the same files are changed on both sides (develop branch and Perforce branch), you will get merge conflicts.

You need to manually resolve the merge conflicts before you can successfully complete the merge. If your git repository is hosted on Azure DevOps, you can use the Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension to manually resolve the merge conflicts from the web UI of the pull request.
When resolving the conflicts, you can select to:

keep changes only from the Perforce branch side.
keep changes only from the develop branch side.
adjust contents of the modified files to Keep certain changes from both side (develop branch and Perforce branch).


After resolving the merge conflicts, you can merge new changes from Perforce branch to feature branch. It will merge the changes you selected when resolving the merge conflicts.



Have you tried with the steps shared in mu answer above? Does it work for you? @TiboVh
